# How to reference to a numbered list item

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In my language when I need to add more context/explanation to an item in a numbered list, I write it like so:

> 1. First.
> 2. Second.
>
> *ad* 1. [text augmenting Item 1].

The *ad* is from Latin; thus, I figured it was used in English as well, but when I did use it, some readers were puzzled and asked me what I meant.

Comment: You could use a superscript "leader" for one.

Comment: Note how you referenced an item from the list yourself in your post by writing "item 1". Why not use that?

Answer (score 1):

A probably more well known tag (also derived from Latin) might be **Re** (see [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/re)). Thus:

> 1. The first thing.
> 2. The second thing.
>
> *Re* 1: This also includes the other thing.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than *to* or *on*, "ad" associates with Anno Domini first and foremost with many English speakers.

You might want to try "(see 1.)" or just "(1)".

Comment: Wouldn’t Anno Domini be A.D. rather that “ad”?

Comment: @RoaringFish Now you're being pedantic just to spite me.

Comment: Not at all. The use of "ad" as in 'to' is far from uncommon - a whole load of logical  fallacies use it for example, such as "ad populum" or "ad hominem", and it is a very different format to the initialism A.D. Kind of hard to see how many English speakers would confuse the two things...

Comment: Doesn't (see 1.) implying the opposite? Something like go there and see the full explanation (something like reference to tables or images)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to insert "ad" or anything else. You can simply insert subscripted bullets (numbers) in the footer part of the page.

Example:

1. Shirt
2. Coffee <sup>a</sup>
3. Computer

---

**<sub>a. Is a type of beverage</sub>**

---

[Chicago manual: footnote and citation.](https://www.citefast.com/styleguide.php?style=Chicago&sec=inte)

[image]

Comment: Interesting idea, but how to use it in an email? Or what if the text in the footer will be on more lines? Is it OK?

Comment: @Artholl You have asked two different questions.

Comment: When I write it in my language with *ad*, I am able to use it everywhere (book, email, forum) and it could be as long as it needs to be. I am just asking if there is something similarly universal in English. I like your answer, but I am not able to use it everywhere or maybe I just overcomplicated things.

Comment: @Artholl check the updated answer. This style is universally accepted.

Comment: @Artholl if there is no more lines then you need to re adjust text. Keep those section of text on same page which has subscripts.

Comment: You are the first one (for me) who use subscript instead of superscript for this. Still it looks strange for me to have few items in a list and several paragraphs under the line, but it looks that it is either that, or insert all text to the list (maybe as second level).

Comment: @Artholl you can use superscript (which I have edited). Secondly,  there are sever books which contains several superscripts in footer region of physical as well as ebook.