# How to refer to an item in a numbered list?

Tags: lists

Let's say I've described an algorithm using numbered list:

> 1. If the types of 'x' and 'y' are the same, return strict equality comparison result.
> 2. If one of them is 'null' and the other is 'undefined', return 'true'.
> 3. If one of them is String and the other is Number, cast String value to Number and try again from the 1st step.
> 4. If one of them is Boolean, cast it to Number.
> 5. If one of them is Object, cast it to a primitive and try again from the 1st step.
> 6. Otherwise return 'false'.

Later I'm explaining something related to this algorithm. How should I refer to the certain step of this list?

I mean, in this example I've already used “1st step”, which is fine. But I'm interested in a more generic way to refer items in a list by their index.

In Russian we have a form “п. 1” which stands for “пункт 1”, which is something like “item 1” / “point 1” / “step 1”. Is there anything like this in English?

I've searched for the similar questions and found these two:

1. [How to reference to a numbered list item](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/461270/how-to-reference-to-a-numbered-list-item)
2. [How do we refer to a item in a numbered list](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/524337/how-do-we-refer-to-a-item-in-a-numbered-list)

The first one seems too specific. I've never seen “Re” anywhere. The second one suggests to use numbers in parens like this:

> The reason is described in (1) of the algorithm.

But it does not feel correct. Or does it? If so, should I always use '(N)' form, or the formatting depends on how the lists look like? Should I use 'N.' in my case?

> The reason is described in 1. of the algorithm.

Can you, please, explain how should I do it properly? Examples from news or books would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I've not come across anything more succinct than 'list item 5' or, where appropriate, 'step 2'. The pilcrow (¶) and the silcrow (§) are normally used only to mark new paragraphs and sections (not necessarily respectively). The hash mark (#) is a general marker for ordered data, so would work, but it is not specific to overt lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not come across anything reserved for lists more succinct than 'list item 5' or, where appropriate, 'step 2 [in the list]'.

The pilcrow (¶) and the silcrow (§) are normally used only to mark new paragraphs and sections (not necessarily respectively).

The hash mark (#) is a general marker for ordinal or arbitrarily
ordered nominal data, so would work, but its use is not specific to
overt lists.

> The symbol has historically been used for a wide range of purposes
> including the designation of an ordinal number

[[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign)]

Hence:

- The reason is described in #1 of the algorithm.

But the list items should then be marked #1, #2 ... rather than 1), 2) ....

Comment: It looks like nobody else is going to answer the question. So, thank you, Edwin! I will probably try to stick with “list item 5” and “step 2” options.

Comment: Yes, it's one of those areas where someone unfamiliar with the conventions worries about correctness, while those seasoned Anglophones reading are trying to understand the content and hardly notice the choice of formatting (provided it's clear).